# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent isFillable() discrepancy in unit tests

Tags: laravel, phpunit, eloquent, codeception

Is there a reason why Eloquent ignores the fillable settings for a model when used in a unit test?

In a non test situation, I get the following output, which is correct, since the model only allows certain fillable fields:

```
$m = new Model();
dd($m->isFillable('nonexistent_field')); --> false
```

But if I do the same thing in a unit test:

```
$m = new Model();
dd($m->isFillable('nonexistent_field')); --> true
```

This is breaking all of my tests. How can I force Eloquent to respect the fillable rules I set for it so the unit tests actually match reality?

Comment: Try putting `Eloquent::reguard()` before your test or in your `setUp()`.

Comment: That fixed it. If you want points make it an official answer and I will pick it. Do you know why Eloquent unguards its models when in unit tests?

Comment: No idea why it does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into this as well. Apparently Laravel unguards models during unit tests so you have to reguard them with `Eloquent::reguard()`. I would put it in the `setUp()` method so it runs before every test.